# Mass deployment of WIndows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows

I work in an office as "kind of" an IT person. I have lots of hardware/software experience, but not in any enterprise capacity.

There are 140 computers total, and they want me to update all of them to Windows 7 (currently on Windows XP). They are all networked. I have created a custom ISO with all the pre-installed software they use. I want to push all of these out to install Windows 7 all at once rather than going from computer to computer.

What is the easiest/fastest/best method of achieving this? I am new to this type of work, so I could use lots of resources tips.

Answer (score 0):

[Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) is what I've used for large deployments like this.  I hope all the machines are identical, or close to.